# Finding a node in a binary tree by looking at the path between it and the root

Tags: algorithms, graphs, binary-trees, randomized-algorithms

There is a directed binary tree as shown in the picture (all edges are diercted from higher- to lower-level nodes). In that tree there is some specific unknown node $s$. All nodes in the $(s, root)$ path are marked somehow (yellow nodes in the picture) so we can check using a $check$ operation if a node belongs to the path. The total length of the path (number of the edges) is $l$ and its value is unknown (in the picture $l=2$). The task is to find the node $s$ using a **randomized** algorithm such that it is expected to use $check$ operation at most $\frac{3}{2}l$ times.

[image]

Comment: What's your question?  We're a question-and-answer site, not a homework help site, so you need to articulate a specific question about your task.  We're not really looking for posts that just describe an exercise-style task and expect someone to solve it for you.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.